# linux ftp mget using ftp MULTI-FETCHING or cURL

Tags: linux, macos, curl, ftp

I need to allow new users do a daily ftp mget of many files with the same filename format, "*.zip".   On the ftp site the download directory is /data/autouploaded.

While there are lots of ways to do this, I wanted to try doing it a shell script with the multi-fetching capabilities of the mac/linux ftp command or the curl command.

I can almost get the ftp command to work:

```
ftp ftp://user:password@ftp.mycompany.com/%2fdata/autoupload
```

but this says "No such file 'autouploaded"  So add the trailing slash:

```
ftp ftp://user:password@ftp.mycompany.com/%2fdata/autoupload/
```

That just opens an interactive shell at the ftp site.

Well, how about adding the filenames as a glob at the end of the url?  Nope.  that tries to do an upload (put).

So, method 1.  HOw do I say mget with the ftp command?

Alternately, I could use curl.  Only, I can't find a word about mget with curl.  The filenames are NOT sequential so the range feature in curl makes no sense.

Suggestions?  Help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search gave me this link: [Scripting FTP access](http://www.stratigery.com/scripting.ftp.html)

The quick summation is to use `<<` to inject commands to the FTP client.

Comment: Yes, well I have a beautifully working ooRexx script.  I was hoping for a one-liner.  I do sort of like the .netrc approach.

Comment: The link provided and the right phrase to stick into Google search  helped lead me to expect, which turned out to be the elected approach.  Thanks, @HonkyTonk.